# uwp localization with 1 resource file for all variants of a language

Tags: xaml, uwp, localization, windows-10, windows-store

I know how localization in uwp works and I currently have **en-US** and **es-es** Resouce files.

What I want to ask is can I just use 1 resource file i.e **en** and will that affect all variants of English language? like **en-us** , **en-as** and all others? and then 1 file for **Spanish** i.e : **es** and so on.

all language variants have only few differences between them which are negligible almost in my app. I noticed my app has most of its users from **Spain** and **US** only. I assume that is because I am only supporting these 2 languages right now. So I want to support all variants of Spanish and all variants of English but only with 2 files, would that work or do I need to provide 1 file for each variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with single file by just using short language name. In your case, it should be Resources.en.resx for english and Resources.es.resx for spanish. You can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx) for language tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking first if the current app language is any english variant (en-US, en-AS, ...) and if it's true then override it with the one you want.

```
If ( CurretLanguage == "en-US" || CurrentLanguage == "en-AS" || ...) 
{
      Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
}
```

Comment: but if I just want all english variants to have same text then I do not need to do this check right?

Comment: This way you can have a resource.resx file and if the user is using any of the english variants, the aplication is showed with your strings for all the variants.

And the same for all the spanish variants. You "obligue" the app to override OS language with the one you want, so narrow the possibilities and only have two resource files.

Comment: sorry its a little bit confusing. currently I have just 2 folders. "en" and "es" for english and spanish respectively, now as per cascading rule, "en/Resources" should be used no matter what english variant the user device has right? Now please explain why I need to perform this code check, isnt the code valid if I have a folder "en-us" instead of just "en" ?

Comment: Here you have more info regarding your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/how-rms-matches-lang-tags

Go to examples where the explanations are most comprehensible.